# How can you center a huxtable?

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]I've looked around and cannot find the answer to this anywhere in the documentation.

When creating a `huxtable` and knitting it in an R markdown document, there seems to be no way to center the table.

Rmd code to replicate is below. I've made the table rather wide to illustrate the point. The left hand margins are exceptionally wide. I've tried to center it with `position(ht) <- "center"` and this doesn't work.

````
---
title: "Example"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE)
````

```
iris_lm <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = iris)

ht <- huxtable::huxreg(iris_lm, iris_lm, iris_lm, iris_lm)

ht
```

Comment: A semi-acceptable workaround I discovered is that you can convert the table to markdown, copy that to the clipboard, then paste it into the Rmd.

`clipr::write_clip(to_md(ht))` writes the table to your clipboard. Then paste it.

Comment: Very confusing... looking, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389565/10371) the LaTeX code looks correct to me.

Comment: Have you tried reading `?"huxtable-FAQ"` or "?position" - the suggestion there is to set the width explicitly.

Comment: It looks like there is some new development on the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Short answer is that this seems to be a known issue without a good solution available:
>
> [**pdf issues** (huxtable GitHub)](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/6)

The default `position` for `huxtable` tables is `"center"`, so your code *should* yield the desired result. However, there seems to be an issue with how `huxtable` processes margins. I have tried coercing the table to `"left"`, `"right"`, and `"center"` as seen below, respectively:

#### Left Aligned

[image: Left-aligned]

#### Right Aligned

[image: Right-aligned]

#### Centered

[image: Center-aligned]

You'll notice that while the left-aligned table is positioned as expected, the right-aligned one is touching the edge of the page. In the centered table, you can see that the table is essentially centered if the right margin is ignored. **This makes me think that this issue is caused by `huxtable` somehow ignoring the right margin.**

Finally, note that setting margins using `geometry:` in the LaTeX header does not resolve this issue either.

### UPDATE:

There seems to have been some more recent development on the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/122).

Comment: Nice digging. You might want to file a new issue on Github - you've uncovered a lot more than what was presented in the issue you reference.

Comment: Even though the answer is "it's borked" this is a rather satisfying "it's borked" answer. Much appreciated. Per, @Gregor's suggestion, I would also ask for you to submit an issue.

Comment: Package author here. I don't think this answer is correct. The simpler answer, as `?position` says, is that you need to set width explicitly if you want `"center"` to work. The reason is to do with how tabularx prints tables in TeX.

Comment: I did see that mentioned in https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/6 and in the documentation, but when I tried setting `huxtable::width(ht)` to pretty much any value (I believe 0.5 is the default), it did *not* help.